# Why the python interpreter run in terminal change to path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I run python in VSCode.

And it was ' E:\USER\Coding\RandomWork> python e:/USER/Coding/RandomWork/src/Elevator.py'

But now it changes to 'E:\USER\Coding\RandomWork> & "F:/Program Files/Python38/python.exe" e:/USER/Coding/RandomWork/src/Elevator.py'

I dont change any settings in VSCode.

Is there anyone knowing why this happens?

Comment: which is true. but it does not change the issue though...

Comment: Does it make a difference when you run the code ? it looks like it simply adds an absolute path to python's. If  `F:/Program Files/Python38/` is in your shell path then it should work either way.

Comment: i know, just trying to figure out why it turns from command to absolute path to run code.

Comment: absolute path includes the name of the executable (python.exe), so there is no magic conversion between a command and a path, this is really just the same program being referenced in another way. It does it probably in case there is other python somewhere in PATH, so it will avoid change in VS if PATH is modified.